# C# CheckBox to Button

Tags: c#, button, checkbox

I am making a Program, which has two checkboxes in a windows form. The first CheckBox is for clearing a file, the other for printing it out. But the final selection, the starting of the method is a button. I wanna make something like an if-statement like "if checkbox1 is clicked do this and this". But it should be fired by the Button.

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked? If you haven't tried anything yet, this is not the best place to come for coding lessons.

Comment: I know how to do that in the CheckBox event, but i dont know how to connect that with the Button event, that the button finally fires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in button's event:

```
if (checkbox1.Checked)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, while editing the form in the visual designer, if you double click on the button, you'll be taken to the code file. It'll have generated a method for you, called `(name of your button)_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)`. It will also be bound to the button click automatically. Just put your code in there.

Comment: Yes i know that. I mean how can i let the button know, that if the CheckBox is checked, it should print/ delete what else.

Comment: In that case check Fuad's answer.

Comment: That's because there was a typo in there. The property you want to use is `Checked`, capital C.